# special characters turn into question marks php html

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, character, meta-tags

I read all the topics found on stackoverflow and other forums, it's hosted on hostgator and I've never had problems with their servers before although quotes for example are transformed into question marks, normal ones not with black diamonds or anything. Here is what I've tried:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

This is what I use for doctype if that matters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I use Unitron for osx to write my code and I've checked that the files should include utf-8.

And the text that I am trying to display is just html, within a php page.

Anyone have any clue on how to help me?

Comment: Are you talking about user input? Are you storing it in a database? When does it "turn into question marks"? This question needs a lot of detail adding.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem page?

Comment: quotes are transformed into question marks? try using stripslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string() ...Please provide more info.

Comment: http://socialscenes.co.uk/v1-5/termsandconditions.php

Not user input, just html output within a php page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert any entities in your text to html entities; for example, the copyright sign will become © `&copy;`

Comment: It is not actually php producing this text but html, it's just within a php page..

Comment: If the content with the special characters in it is not dynamic, you can put it through this function once, and paste the output into your html page. This way, you don't call this function for every request, reducing the latency.

Answer (score 3):

Check that your file is encoded in UTF8, for instance with Notepad++ go to "Encoding" > "Convert in UTF8" and save the file.

Comment: He stated that file is in UTF-8.
However the right option is: "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM"

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Check that quotation marks you have in you html are really quotation marks. They can be some other characters that just looks the same but aren't. This can happen when copy-pasting from some other source.

Try rewriting part of code that is causing the problem by hand.

If that's not the case, try using one or both of these php functions:
[mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)
[mb_http_output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-output.php)

Also your HTML is not valid: [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsocialscenes.co.uk%2Fv1-5%2Ftermsandconditions.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)